# Express SQL query in programming language

Tags: php, database

It is hard to express SQL language in programming language.

For example this query:

```
select * from users
where exists (
    select 1 from videos 
    where
    concat(users.first_name, ' ', users.last_name) ILIKE videos.title
)
```

Ignore the fact that the query is not optimized or silly, this is just an example.

You have joins, operators, functions in sql.

I want to аvoid sql in the methods - the sql should be in the model or database library.

So do you have any suggestions about the query, for example.

```
Users.whereExists(
...
)
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not using the same system that doctrine (and maybe others), something like this https://imgur.com/JfQ9yV2
Well that's a bit reinventing the wheel, but it works.

Comment: To my mind the application should only interface with the `User` model using something like `User::exists()` - the `User` model has it's own database interface model that's optimised for whatever database you happen to be using (e.g. it holds the optimised query). Outside of the database interface layer, the rest of the application shouldn't *need* to talk to the database anyway... unless you're actually writing a portable framework. Just my tuppence worth.

Comment: But for example concat function does it belong to the user or the database class?

Comment: In this example? In the database class since you're dealing specifically with how the data is structured - e.g. you appear to be looking for a substring within `videos.title` ... that doesn't necessarily mean you need to do it in the SQL of course.

Comment: But I want to use only the model. This is better at least in the books, because If i change the database, I will change the models and it will work. But if I use methods from the database in the controller it will be harder maybe

Comment: You wouldn't use database methods in the controller, the controller only talks to the `User` model... the `User` model talks to the `UserDatabase` model (or whatever naming convention you use) to retrieve the data and update itself. You *should* be able, in theory, to switch out the entire database by just updating the database interface classes - or create interface classes for several database servers. You can use an ORM for that, but you don't *need* to.

Answer (score 0):

As i have understood that you don't like to write sql code into your programming language file, regarding for same i have a simple idea.

1) just make a stored procedure in mysql db through this code

    `DELIMITER //
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS procedure_name;//
    CREATE PROCEDURE procedure_name()
    BEGIN
        select * from   users
        where exists (
            select 1 
            from videos 
            where concat(users.first_name, ' ', users.last_name)

            LIKE videos.title
        )
    END;`

2) Then fire this statement into your programming file code `"call procedure_name;"`

by this way you have replaced all code by single line statement.

Comment: It works, but the query is dynamic. What I mean is that I have some filters, and depending on them I generate the query. Where exists clause could or could not exists, Also this is simple query. When I have large query like 20-50 lines i have hard time to declare it with methods in the programming language of choice. If I add one procedure for all combinations it will be very combinations and complex logic.

Comment: My friend, if your query is dynamic then this procedure will able to work with dynamic perimeters as well like this  

<code>CREATE PROCEDURE procedure_name(perameter_1 CHAR(32),perameter_2 INT UNSIGNED , PhoneNumber VARCHAR(20) )<code>

in this you will be able to pass every parameters as per your need